# python android selenium send_keys BACK_SPACE

Tags: python, selenium, testing, appium, backspace

Impossible to delete the last letter in imput text, ???

```
appium.find_element_by_id("title").send_keys("totot")
appium.find_element_by_id("title").send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
```

Comment: when doing "send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)", the text is all selected by the keyboard

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you perform the same steps manually? Post a link to the site?

Comment: i use appium Android input manager for unicode.. and manually doesn t happen

Comment: @langme, try to add `appium.find_element_by_id("title").click()` between those lines- this should unselect text and put cursor in the end of line

Comment: already done.. doesn t work @Andersson

Comment: @langme, ok. What if to try `appium.find_element_by_id("title").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)` between those lines?

Comment: @Andersson 'appium.find_element_by_id("title").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)' clear text

Comment: @langme You probably need to use Actions and string the 2 together in one action. It might be that it refocuses the element with a new command, causing the text to be selected.

Comment: I believe in python `ActionChains` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @langme, provide some more info, e.g. HTML, page URL, etc... as it doesn't look like common case

Comment: @anderson it is for android App

Comment: @anderson may be due to a selected keyboard... i could choose GO Lite Keyboard and not default appium keyboard..But how do you do ?

Comment: @langme moving my comment from the deleted answer here. You were still doing 2 separate actions in your example. It should have been something like this... `actions.find_element_by_id("title").send_keys("totot").send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)`. Then you can call `actions.perform` and it'll do all those steps like a user stringing those steps together. If you need to check something before the backspace that's fine, in that case you would just string the actions together after and probably just send the right key before the backspace.

Answer (score -1):

the goal is to change the keyboard
replace :

```
appium.activate_ime_engine('io.appium.android.ime/.UnicodeIME')
```

by :

```
appium_driver.activate_ime_engine('com.jb.gokeyboard/.GoKeyboard')
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer? Or if it is I'm not sure I understand it.

Comment: A little bit of an explanation as to how this works and how it solves the question would be helpful. Remember than our answers are supposed to be instructive!

Comment: the answer is that the useful keyboard has an importance..i used a default keyboard appium but it has a restriction about functionality (ex backspace)